# Removing a number after a word in a string in R

Tags: r, regex

I would like to remove the first number in the string below:

```
str = "Sitting on 1 chair. Another 4 chairs and 3 books are in the room."
```

More specifically, I would like regex that targets the number after "on ". Targeting the first number in the series will not work for me. I have tried variations on this code:

```
str_extract_all(str, "(?=\\s*(on*))[0-9]")
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you want as the answer.  The number? or everything in the string except the number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separating numbers from a list of numbers and letters in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521185/separating-numbers-from-a-list-of-numbers-and-letters-in-r)

Comment: Apologies for the possible duplicate. The other question was badly worded, and didn't seem to capture my intent very well. I have removed that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this helps

```
as.numeric(str_extract_all(str, "(?<=\\b(on)\\s)[0-9]")[[1]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed! I can see that I really need to understand regex better. If you have any suggestions for training on regex, please let me know.